# Magento - Add subtotal for custom options into backend order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have products with custom attribute, and I can see my c.options into cart ( when I select it ). Now i need to save a subtotal amount of the products with c.options selected to the backend.
Is it possible?

edit:

my custom option to each products is a select with this options:

```
<option>Add to bag 1</option>
<option>Add to bag 2</option>
<option>Add to bag 3</option>
<option>Add to bag 3</option>
```

So i need to group the product with same option and have a subtotal for that products.
Hope you understand!

Comment: why you need it, it's nonsense

Comment: edited my question, hope u understand.

Comment: have you looked into configurable, grouped, bundled products?

Comment: But my clients can create a grouped product in frontend...

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this by modifing your basket template file where you then group your products by whatever you want and display subtotals as much as you want.